# AngluarJS: using filter in controller

Tags: angularjs

I have this controller:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter',
    function($scope, $filter) {
      $scope.users = [{
        name: "Hanna",
        gender: "female"
      }, {
        name: "Martin",
        gender: "male"
      }, {
        name: "Kim",
        gender: "transgender"
      }];

      $scope.traditionalUsers = $filter('filter')($scope.users,femaleOrMale());

      function femaleOrMale(user) {
        return ['female','male'].indexOf(user.gender);
      }
    }
  ]);
```

I want to filter users that has a property that matches an array. This does not work. See [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/0BfQ3p?p=preview). How can I correctly call the filter-filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `()`

You're calling the `femaleOrMale` function without any parameters when you write `femaleOrMale()` in

```
$scope.traditionalUsers = $filter('filter')($scope.users, femaleOrMale());
```

What you write to pass the function itself to the filter is

```
$scope.traditionalUsers = $filter('filter')($scope.users, femaleOrMale);
```

This will make the page not throw an error anymore, however it wont display `male` and `female` as traditional users, which i suspect is what you want. You need to return a boolean from the `femaleOrMale` filter, and `indexOf` returns the index of the match, or `-1` if there is no match, so compare for `-1`.

```
return ['female','male'].indexOf(user.gender) != -1;
```

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter',
    function($scope, $filter) {
      $scope.users = [{
        name: "Hanna",
        gender: "female"
      }, {
        name: "Martin",
        gender: "male"
      }, {
        name: "Kim",
        gender: "transgender"
      }];

      $scope.traditionalUsers = $filter('filter')($scope.users, femaleOrMale);

      function femaleOrMale(user) {
        return ['female','male'].indexOf(user.gender) != -1;
      }
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-app='myApp'>
      <div ng-controller='testCtrl'>
        <h3>Male and female users:</h3>
        {{traditionalUsers}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @EricC Please contemplate to import the specific filter you're using, i.e. `filterFilter` instead of `$filter`, to simplify unit testing.